# How to use tamil text as input in android

Tags: android, input, locale

I am creating an android application in which i have used the south indian language to display the text in tamil for which i have converted all the strings to tamil but i need to give the inputs in edit text as tamil.

How can i do this if the user doesn't have a tamil keyboard installed with them can anyone show me some examples for input the text in android with local languages.What i have done so far is converted the strings to tamil but i want to give the inputs in tamil.I have tried using some examples which gives the values as tamil but it dosn't shows how to give the inputs in tamil.

Answer (score 0):

The only option would be to create a custom [`Keyboard`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) for your app, you have little to no control over the system `InputMethod`.